# Bottom navigation bar - ripple effect over system navigation

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I need to make ripple effect of bottom navigation bar over system navigation bar (like gdrive etc.)

I tried to make system navigation bar transparent but ripple effect was still cropped.
Any hint what should I set or where is the problem?

thx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_calendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/namesListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"></ListView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp10"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        style="@style/BottomNavigation"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: You are restricting the view of your bottom bar or bottom bar item. This could be because of a misplaced padding. Please show your xml code.

Comment: In my opinion it should be placed on right place. Apps like Google photos, Google fit, Google books have the same cropped ripple effect. Google drive, Slack etc. have ripple effect which I need. I am not quite sure whether system navigation bar is displayed correctly

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but you have to [display content edge-to-edge in your app](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge).